# Showing Target class [App\\Http\\Middleware\\JwtMiddleware] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, middleware

When trying to login it gives me the following error:

```json
{
    "message": "Target class [App\\Http\\Middleware\\JwtMiddleware] does not exist.",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException",
    "file": "/home/u476373343/domains/xyz.com/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php"
}
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class Jwtmiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof TokenInvalidException) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Invalid']);
            } else {
                if ($e instanceof TokenExpiredException) {
                    return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Expired']);
                } else {
                    if ($e instanceof JWTException) {
                        return response()->json(['status' => 'Token could not be parsed']);
                    } else {
                        return response()->json(['status' => 'Authorized token not found']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

##### `api.php`

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.verify']], function () {
    Route::post('getmenuitem', [MenuTypeController::class, 'getMenuItemData']);
});
```

##### `Kernel.php`

```php
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'jwt.verify' => \App\Http\Middleware\JwtMiddleware::class,
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems like the issue is with the case sensitivity of the class name. In your `Kernel.php` file, you have registered the middleware as `JwtMiddleware` but the actual class name is `Jwtmiddleware`.

To fix this issue, you should rename the class `Jwtmiddleware` to `JwtMiddleware` in your middleware file.

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class JwtMiddleware
{
    // ...
}
```

And make sure the file name is also `JwtMiddleware.php`. After making these changes, try running your application again.